# XSLT Pattern matching - Remove Ancestors

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, reporting-services

I'm exporting bar graph data from SSRS as XML and most of the time it looks great but in some cases it gets /SeriesX/CategoryX/ nodes.  When .net reads those into a datatable the dat gets split out into three related tables; Series0, Category0, and Value.

I need to remove /SeriesX/CategoryX/ from this:

```
  <My_Location_Chart>
    <Series0>
      <Category0>
        <Value Y="0.1111" />
      </Category0>
    </Series0>
    <Series1>
      <Category0>
        <Value Y="0.2222" />
      </Category0>
    </Series1>
    <Series2>
      <Category0>
        <Value Y="0.3333" />
      </Category0>
    </Series2>
  </My_Location_Chart>
```

So it looks like this:

```
  <My_Location_Chart>
      <Value Y="0.1111" />
      <Value Y="0.2222" />
      <Value Y="0.3333" />
  </My_Location_Chart>
```

There are other charts that use SeriesX values and I don't want to screw those up, but none are in the pattern of /SeriesX/CategoryX/, so I only want to match that pattern.

I have tried the following to remove the Category nodes. It's close, but not exactly what I need:

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*[text()[normalize-space()] | @*])]"/>


  <xsl:template match="rep:Category0" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>
```

The above creates this:

```
  <My_Location_Chart>
    <Series0>
      <Value Y="0.1111" />
    </Series0>
    <Series1>
      <Value Y="0.2222" />
    </Series1>
    <Series2>
      <Value Y="0.3333" />
    </Series2>
  </My_Location_Chart>
```

Any suggestions are welcome. I'm new to XSLT to go easy on me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something simple?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/My_Location_Chart">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*/Category0/Value"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this won't change "0.711590296495957" into "0.813084112149533" as shown in your example.

Comment: I like simple.  I cleaned up the element values for clarity. As a newbie I'm reading this and it seems to make perfect sense, but it doesn't change the output at all. I can't figure out why because it looks good to me. My_Location_Chart is under other trees, so technically it's /Report/My_Location_Chart/ but that should be fine...

Comment: "*My_Location_Chart is under other trees*" Then this cannot work as is, because it assumes that `My_Location_Chart` is the root element. Try changing `<xsl:template match="/My_Location_Chart">` to `<xsl:template match="/Report/My_Location_Chart">` or `<xsl:template match="My_Location_Chart">`. If it still doesn't work, post a representative sample of your input.